# Windows Command Prompt %COMMANDS%? How many are there?

Tags: windows, command, prompt, temp

`%windir%` = Jumps to c:\Windows\

`%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe` = Opens gui task manager.

`%HOMEDRIVE%` = Jumps to C:

`%HOMEPATH%` = Jumps to Current User's folder.
C:\Windows\System32>taskmgr.exe = Opens Task Manager.

`%temp%` = Goes to your Temporary Window Files Temp Files are usually created by your screen corders, or any program that you open.

That's the ones that I've discovered, how many are there? how can I find them, and what are they called? Before learning that I would've had to type,

```
cd c:\users\Username\Desktop
```

After learning, it shorten's the command down to

```
cd %homepath%\Desktop
```

I am very interested in learning more of these navigational commands if there are any. Thanks for any answers including new ones, or any information on them.

Comment: `%VARIABLE%` is CMD's syntax for accessing an environment variable named `VARIABLE`. Every process has an environment block (PEB) that contains process data that's directly available (i.e. doesn't require a system call). Included within this is a block for storing environment variables, which is accessed via Windows API functions such as `GetEnvironmentVariable`. Variable names are case insensitive. CMD's `set` command can list variables, e.g. `set t` will list all that begin with "t". CMD actually uses copies of the process environment variables to enable local scopes via `setlocal`.

Comment: Thank You very much for the very clear answer, I used "set" in command which displayed a lot more %commands% that I did not know and helped me out a great deal. You got the Best Answer. When I am able to give a best answer. Thank You Very Much for helping me with my curiosity.